# Android:Realm Migration Exception

Tags: android, realm

I am using gradele version: compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.5'.

In my application file I have written code as follows

```
 RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
                                            .schemaVersion(2)
                                            .migration(new Migration())
                                            .build();


        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
```

In my activities/fragment I open realm instances as follows

```
@Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }


@Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        realm.close();
    }
```

But I always ran into an exception as follows

```
 03-10 14:55:32.385 7015-7015/com.workoutguru.workoutcash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-10 14:55:32.385 7015-7015/com.workoutguru.workoutcash E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.workoutguru.workoutcash, PID: 7015
    03-10 14:55:32.385 7015-7015/com.workoutguru.workoutcash E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file. 
    03-10 14:55:32.385 7015-7015/com.workoutguru.workoutcash E/AndroidRuntime: Cached configuration: 
    03-10 14:55:32.385 7015-7015/com.workoutguru.workoutcash E/AndroidRuntime: realmFolder: /data/data/com.workoutguru.workoutcash/files
    03-10 14:55:32.385 7015-7015/com.workoutguru.workoutcash E/AndroidRuntime: realmFileName : default.realm
    03-10 14:55:32.385 7015-7015/com.workoutguru.workoutcash E/AndroidRuntime: canonicalPath: /data/data/com.workoutguru.workoutcash/files/default.realm
    03-10 14:55:32.385 7015-7015/com.workoutguru.workoutcash E/AndroidRuntime: key: [length: 0]
    E/AndroidRuntime: schemaVersion: 2
     E/AndroidRuntime: migration: E/AndroidRuntime: 
    durability: FULL
     schemaMediator: io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator@a3db7d18
```

My code for migration file is as follows

```
public class Migration implements RealmMigration {

    @Override
    public void migrate(final DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion){

        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

        if(oldVersion == 1){
            RealmObjectSchema sweatPointSchema = schema.get("UserInfoDB");
                    sweatPointSchema.addField("sweatPoints",Integer.class);

            oldVersion++;
        }

        if(oldVersion == 2){
            RealmObjectSchema teamInfoSchema = schema.get("TeamInfoDB");
                    teamInfoSchema.addField("teamDescription",String.class);

            oldVersion ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely there is one place where you are using `Realm.getInstance(context)` or `Realm.getInstance(configuration)` which uses a different configuration object.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior So I Have to make sure whether its activity of fragment I need to use Default configuration. Am I right??

Comment: You have to use `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` everywhere. I would assume it is fairly easy to check. Just search for `Realm.getInstance` in all your files.

Comment: What is the code doing around the place where the exception is thrown? You cut the Exception message before it shows your code.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior As guided by you I have done the successful Changes and app does not crash any more. However say i have added a string field to table after exporting the database I am unable to see column in the table. Do I have to specifically also add string into the class file generating its getter and setter??

Comment: @ChristianMelchior I added the field in the class with getter and setter and it works I hope I am on right track.